# Measure with a Value from corresponding attribute dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a Measure with 2 Dimensions: `Cars` and `Routes`.
For each Car there is only 1 corresponding `Route`.
I need to create a new measure that shows `Route` `Name` attribute for each member in `Cars` dimension.

Now we Measure look like this:

[image]

But I need to create a string Measure with no agregation, so data starts looks like at the next picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is valid to use the following within a measure when writing mdx queries:

```
... .CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERCAPTION
```

If the attribute is on rows as your first screenshot shows then this measure will return its caption